# Storing themes on the different pages of the site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good afternoon to you in the community, I'm here to know how to use the code in the context of localStorage. I would like to store with the same one of the different themes chosen by the user that then allows them to be applied in the different pages that the user will visit. How can I do this?

Attached the HTML code and scripts:

```
<footer class="center blur padding-16">
        <p class="bold">NewTechSlyDev_</p>
        <div class="mini-grid-container" id="myThemes">
            <div class="default-theme mini-polaroid circle little-resize pointer" data-tema="" title="Default"></div>
            <div class="dark-theme mini-polaroid circle little-resize pointer" data-tema="dark" title="Dark"></div>
            <div class="transparent-theme mini-polaroid circle little-resize pointer" data-tema="transparent" title="Transparent"></div>
            <div class="apricot-theme mini-polaroid circle little-resize pointer" data-tema="apricot" title="Apricot"></div>
            <div class="past-theme mini-polaroid circle little-resize pointer" data-tema="past" title="Past"></div>
            <div class="panorama-theme mini-polaroid circle little-resize pointer" data-tema="panorama" title="Panorama"></div>
            <div class="blank-theme mini-polaroid circle little-resize pointer" data-tema="blank" title="Blank"></div>
            <div class="slimanoworld-theme mini-polaroid circle little-resize pointer" data-tema="slimanoworld" title="SlimanoWorld"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function scegliTema(tema) {
                const body = document.body;
                if (body.dataset.tema) body.classList.remove(body.dataset.tema);
                body.dataset.tema = tema;
                if (tema) body.classList.add(tema);
            }
            (() => {
                const elementi = document.querySelectorAll('#myThemes > div');
                for (let i = 0; i < elementi.length; ++i) {
                    const el = elementi[i];
                    const nomeTema = el.dataset.tema ? el.dataset.tema + '-theme' : '';
                    elementi[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                        scegliTema(nomeTema)
                    });
                }
            })();
        </script>
    </footer>
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt in your code to store or retrieve from localStorage.   Have you tried storing the theme name and ran into difficulty?

Comment: Yes, more than anything I was nervous and so I had eliminated the code of the localStorage, so I wanted to know if I could have support to be able to create this fragment, if possible.

Thanks in advance for the answer :)
NewTechSlyDev_

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "create this fragment". Is the code above working within the page it's run in?  If so then is all you're missing how to get it recognized in the other pages that should respect the theme?

Comment: Yes, I simply want the browser to store the last selected theme so that they apply to pages throughout the site.
(I apologize if the English I use is unclear, I do not know English well and "I take inspiration" from the translator)

Thanks in advance for the answer :)
NewTechSlyDev_